# Stuck in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

HI

I am stuck in a scenario where I have a column like

```
          testColumn
           A;B;C;D;E
           A;B
           C;D
```

I want output as separate columns(I have the number of columns like in below example there is always 5 columns)

```
         A B C D E
         x x x x x
         x x
             X X
```

Comment: @Cristian , Hi i tried with case statement but if there is single value in the column i am able to do but if there multiple value separated with colon is bit difficult

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH T(C) AS
(
SELECT 'A;B;C;D;E' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A;B' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C;D'
)
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('A',C) > 0 THEN 'X' ELSE '' END AS 'A',
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('B',C) > 0 THEN 'X' ELSE '' END AS 'B',
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('C',C) > 0 THEN 'X' ELSE '' END AS 'C',
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('D',C) > 0 THEN 'X' ELSE '' END AS 'D',
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('E',C) > 0 THEN 'X' ELSE '' END AS 'E'
FROM T
```

Gives your desired results

```
A    B    C    D    E
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
X    X    X    X    X
X    X              
          X    X
```

Answer (score 0):

build a stored procedure,

this may be a good starting point:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLArrayParameterHandling.aspx

regards,
//t

Answer (score 0):

```
;with TestTable(testColumn) as
(
  select 'A;B;C;D;E' union all
  select 'A;B' union all
  select 'C;D'
)

select
  case when n.r.exist('r[.="A"]') = 1 then 'X' else '' end as A,
  case when n.r.exist('r[.="B"]') = 1 then 'X' else '' end as B,
  case when n.r.exist('r[.="C"]') = 1 then 'X' else '' end as C,
  case when n.r.exist('r[.="D"]') = 1 then 'X' else '' end as D,
  case when n.r.exist('r[.="E"]') = 1 then 'X' else '' end as E
from TestTable
  cross apply (select cast('<r>'+replace(testColumn, ';', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) n(r)
```

Result

```
A    B    C    D    E
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
X    X    X    X    X
X    X              
          X    X
```

Comment: Compared to my answer this seems to have a significantly more expensive overall estimated subtree cost `1.87546` vs `0.0000035` because it invokes the XML reader. Not sure of any circumstances in which this would be of benefit either as it will fail if the strings contain `<` for example?